# Count lists within lists using lambdas

Tags: java

I've got a list of some objects which each further contains another list and I would like to count the number total number of all items in those nested lists. This is how I do it now:

```
int accu = 0;
for (SomeObject so : objects) {
    accu += so.getListWithinObject().size();
}
```

But I feel like this can be written as one line using some Java 8 magic. Probably not even difficult, I just don't know how.

Comment: I think your current code is fine. It's readable and intuitive. The stream api does not necesserarily make code simpler.

Answer (score 6):

I'll list four one-liners. Each one gives the same output:

1. `objects.stream().map(SomeObject::getListWithinObject).flatMap(List::stream).count();`
2. `objects.stream().flatMap(e -> e.getListWithinObject().stream()).count();`
3. `objects.stream().map(e -> e.getListWithinObject().size()).reduce(0, Integer::sum);`
4. `objects.stream().mapToLong(e -> e.getListWithinObject().size()).sum();`

I am sure there are other ways, too. It just shows how powerful the Stream API is; you can perform a single task in multiple ways.

Two more one-liners provided by Eritrean (in comments) without using *mapping*:

5. `objects.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(so -> so.getListWithinObject().size()));`
6. `objects.stream().reduce(0, (subSum, so) -> subSum + so.getListWithinObject().size(), Integer::sum)`

Comment: To add two more alternatives to your already good approachs, but with out the need of mapping:

Comment: `objects.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(so -> so.getListWithinObject().size()));`

Comment: `objects.stream().reduce(0, (subSum, so) -> subSum + so.getListWithinObject().size(),Integer::sum);`

Comment: Thank you @Eritrean for providing 2 more one-liners. I have included them in my answer, too!

Answer (score 5):

If it's just a two-leves structure (so, the inner objects do not contain other lists that you want to sum), you can do like this:

```
objects.stream().map(SomeObject ::getListWithinObject)
       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
       .mapToInt(List::size)
       .sum();
```

Comment: Why the not full filter? This does not seem part of the original code.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo: It will exclude eventual null lists from the count. Do you think it's not necessary? In fact, I did not tested it.

Comment: No, I get it, but it was not on the semantics of the code of the OP. So for me it just makes the stream more complex unnecessarily.

Comment: Oh yes, but just wanted to provide a generally enough solution with a better check.

Answer (score 3):

You *could* stream your collection and then aggregate the sizes into a variable:

```
AtomicInteger total = new AtomicInteger(0);
objects.stream().forEach(o -> total.addAndGet(o.getListWithinObject().size()));
System.out.println("total size is: " + total);
```

But just because a stream could be made to work here does not mean you need to use one.  There is nothing wrong with using an enhanced for loop.

Comment: I think you have misspelled the `forEach` method here.

Comment: But how can you change the value of a final variable within the `forEach` block? It would work with an `AtomicInteger` perhaps, but this way I don’t think this would even compile. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your data looks like

```java
final List<Integer> integers1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
final List<Integer> integers2 = Arrays.asList(5, 6, 7, 8);
final List<Integer> integers3 = Arrays.asList(9, 10, 11, 12);
final List<Integer> integers4 = Arrays.asList(13, 14, 15, 16);

final List<List<Integer>> lists = Arrays.asList(integers1, integers2, integers3, integers4);
```

Now, there are two ways to get the count

```java
lists.stream().flatMap(List::stream) // this flattens the lists to look like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
.count(); // 16
```

and,

```java
lists.stream().mapToLong(List::size) // creates a long stream which looks like [4, 4, 4, 4]
.sum(); // 16
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also possible, but very near to the answer given by @Andrea:

```
Integer accu = objects.stream()
                    .filter(o -> o != null) // may be omitted
                    .map(SomeObject::getListWithinObject)
                    .collect(Collectors.summingInt(List::size));
```